# If I start a bounty, can I lose privileges?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, privileges

Just as an example:

If I have 130 reputation and provide 50 as a bounty for a question, do I lose any of my existing privileges (due to the 130-50 reputation)?

Comment: This info is provided in the Help Center ["Set Bounties"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) and ["What is a Bounty?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) and the FAQ ["How does the bounty system work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/230506), and in the dupe question(s). Searching the Help Center, FAQ, and site does often bring back the answer you require :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, due to the bounty rep being 'spent' - as your new rep would be at 80 (i.e. not able to downvote until you reach 125 again).  But, with good contributions, you'll probably be able to reclaim it in a short amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This helps me. Yes I know that I get it quickly back. But if your on a new community and just want 1-2 questions answered the bounty is good way for this. :-)